# Disabling JBOD mode from command line for LSI (Dell H330)

Tags: dell, lsi, hba, megacli

I'm unable to disable JBOD mode on H330 (dell):

I've tried:

```
megacli   -AdpSetProp  -EnableJBOD -0 -a0

Adapter 0: Failed to Set Adapter Properties.


megacli -CfgClr  -a0


Adapter 0: Failed to Clear Configuration.

FW error description: 
  The requested command is invalid.
```

I can switch H330 to RAID mode in DRAC interface (it's a dell server), but is there a way to perform this switch from within host my means of MegaCLI?

P.S.

I can enable JBOD the same way, but not to disable it:

```
megacli   -AdpSetProp  -EnableJBOD -1 -a0

Adapter 0: Set JBOD to Enable success.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some struggles I found the way.

1. The controller have a limited number of reconfigurations. After certain number a reboot is required.
2. CfgClr helps to clear all possible arrays, etc.
3. After the combination of CfgClr and  `-AdpSetProp  -EnableJBOD -0` drives become "Unconfigured good".